# Is there a good way to determine where an incorrect URI is being requested from?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I've been having a few issues recently where I've had errors like this in the console:

```
GET http://<server>/<context-path>/null 404 (Not Found)
```

(They're not all `null`, that's just the latest example).

Mostly these either don't have a line number shown or bogus ones like `null:1`, which isn't exactly conducive to finding the error. I've been pretty much reduced to painstakingly adding `console.log` messages to try to track down when and where it happens (and in the last case that I've just resolved, inspecting every DOM element until I found the one with `src="null"`).

While (I think) I've managed to find all the current issues, the process was rather painful, so I was wondering if anyone knew of a better approach to these issues? Are there any tools that provide better debug information than the (Chrome) console log in these cases?